# How to save data from multiple select tag in jsp page to DB using Hibernate many-to-many

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jsp

I want to save **user** into database using **hibernate**, mapping : **many-to-many**

> ## POJO's :

### Users.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users_db")
public class Users implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id_user", unique = true, nullable = false)
private long id;

@Column(name = "userName_db")
private String userName;

@Column(name = "email_db")
private String Email;

private String password;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "userskill", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id_user", nullable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id") })
private Set<Skills> skills = new HashSet<Skills>();
// getters ans setters
```

### Skills.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "skillsDB", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint (columnNames ="typeSkill") )
public class Skills implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@Column(name = "typeSkill")
private String typeSkill;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "skills")
private Set<Users> users = new HashSet<Users>();
// getters and setters
```

> ## addUserServlet.java

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    UserService userService = new UserServiceImpl();

    Users user = new Users();

    user.setUserName(request.getParameter("UserName"));
    user.setEmail(request.getParameter("Email"));
    user.setPassword(request.getParameter("Password"));

    Set<Skills> skillSet = new HashSet<Skills>();

    for (int i = 0; i < request.getParameterValues("skills").length; i++) {
        skillSet.add(new Skills(request.getParameterValues("skills")[i]));
    }
    user.setSkills(skillSet);
    userService.add(user);
    request.setAttribute("usersList", userService.showUsers());
    this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/addUser.jsp").forward(request, response);

}
```

> ## UsersDAOImpl.java

```
public List<Users> showUsers() {

    List<Users> result = session.createCriteria(Users.class).list();
    return result;

}
```

> ## Hibernate Configuration

```
<hibernate-configuration>

<session-factory>

    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dictionnaire</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">mosab</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="format_sql">true</property>
    <property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    <!-- Names the annotated entity class -->
    <mapping resource="com.entity.Users" />
    <mapping resource="com.entity.Skills" />

</session-factory>
```

> ## addUser.jsp
>
> **In select tag I get data from database**

```
<form action="adduser" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="name">User name :* </label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="UserName" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td><label for="Email">Email :* </label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="Email" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="Password">Password :*</label></td>
            <td><input type="password" name="Password" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="skills">skills :</label></td>
            <td><select name="skills" multiple="multiple">
                    <c:forEach var="item" items="${skills }">
                        <option value="${item.typeSkill}" ><c:out value="${item.typeSkill}"/></option>
                    </c:forEach>
            </select></td>  
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="Save" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id User</th>
            <th>User name</th>
            <th>password</th>
            <th>email</th>
            <th>Skills</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <c:forEach var="item" items="${usersList}">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${item.id}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${item.userName}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${item.password}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${item.email}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${item.skills}" /></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

> problem : 
>   when I fill inputs and I choose some skills, after submit, In the table I get id, name, email, password successfully,but skills apears like this :

If I choose one skill : 
**[com.entity.Skills@60b7080b]**

If I choose two skills : 
**[com.entity.Skills@60b7080b, com.entity.Skills@5e0659ab]**

So I hope that is clear for you.

Comment: How could computer guess what you want to display? You need to tell it which properties of the `Skills` class to show.

Comment: How can I solve this, I try to do :
  <td><c:out value="${item.skills.typeSkill}" /></td>
but it does not work, I think the problem is here but I cant found the solution : 
public List<Users> showUsers() {
  List<Users> result = session.createCriteria(Users.class).list();
  return result;

Comment: How about iterating through all of the skills and printing the desired property from each skill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Dragan Bozanovic for your help, but I found the solution myself:

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${usersList}">
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${item.id}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${item.userName}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${item.password}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${item.email}" /></td>
                    <td><c:forEach var="skill" items="${item.skills}">
                            <c:out value="${skill.typeSkill}"/> 
                        </c:forEach></td>
                </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Yeap, if you have a property of lists, then you have to iterate each of them to Show on the screen. or else, you'll just have the "list" reference object of the "property".